# Adding Polyline hover effect on custom line chart - SVG/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm creating a custom line chart with CSS using SVG my HTML code looks as follows:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 102" class="chart">
  <polyline
     fill="none"
     stroke="#718cd2"
     stroke-width="1"
     points="
       00,100
       20,60
       40,80
       200, 100
       220, 10
       240, 70
       420, 70
       440, 40
       460, 90
       480, 100
       500, 60
     "
   /> 
</svg>
```

I'm trying to add a hover effect on the meeting point of the polyline points as shown in this photo which you can see highlighted with red circles:[image]

I'm not sure if my method of using SVG is best for this or if this is even possible, I've tried searching over stack overflow but I can only find Googlemaps and leaflet.js related questions, I'm trying to complete this without the use of libraries excluding jQuery and jQuery UI which I already have in my project.

Sorry I wasn't able to provide any code due to not knowing where to even begin or what to try for this

Comment: draw hidden circles at the vertices and have something happen when you click or mouseover the circles.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear or badly worded. I'm trying to find out how to add these hidden circles at the vertices.

Comment: <circle cx="0" cy="100" r="whatever is appropriate" pointer-events="all" fill="none"/> etc.

Comment: Oh, I see! This is very useful as I can just position this according to the points of the graph and it even works dynamically! Thank you a lot @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0):

you can use `circle` elements for each data point and apply a hover effect to those circles. please check on code snippets and [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/o5gckhpz/1/)

```css
.data-point {
  fill: red;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.data-point:hover {
  opacity: 1; /* Show on hover */
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 102" class="chart">
  <g>
    <!-- Polyline -->
    <polyline
      fill="none"
      stroke="#718cd2"
      stroke-width="1"
      points="00,100 20,60 40,80 200,100 220,10 240,70 420,70 440,40 460,90 480,100 500,60"
    />

    <!-- Circles for data points -->
    <circle cx="00" cy="100" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="60" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="80" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="220" cy="10" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="240" cy="70" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="420" cy="70" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="440" cy="40" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="460" cy="90" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="480" cy="100" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <circle cx="500" cy="60" r="4" class="data-point" />
    <!-- Add more circles for other data points -->
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: please see result in run code snippet [ohover effect ] - @conorreidd